# Clang always breaks inheritance list for multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

Want to format my code in this way:

```
class Foo : public Parent1, protected Parent2
{
};
```

However `clang-format` always breaks inheritance list for multiple inheritance like this:

```
class Foo 
    : public Parent1
    , protected Parent2
{
};
```

which is not beautiful and not onvenient. Is there a way to fix this - seems no option for this in [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style option you're looking for is `BreakInheritanceList`. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for details.

When this style option is set to `BeforeComma`, you get the formatting you show above. You might not be setting it explicitly - if your settings are based on the `Mozilla` style then this style option is set to `BeforeComma`.

The default is normally `BeforeColon`, which would probably satisfy you. You could also try `AfterColon` to see if you like it any better.

A good place to experiment with these style options is the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/).

Comment: Yes, You are right: I had `BeforeComma`, `BeforeColon`  - works fine, looks good. Thanks!